# How do we download the values from a Custom Funnel using API / Big Query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

We have built a "closed" custom funnel using Google Analytics 360 which includes Users who have seen a product category page and then seen a Basket Page, and then concluded with an Order Confirmation Page.

Is it possible to download the values from this report via the API/ big query and generate a spreadsheet to use for internal reporting?

Comment: Where does this reporting data live? It's not clear from your question..

Comment: it lives in Google Analytics 360 which gets pushed to big query

Comment: It depends on what your expected end goal is. Have you tried creating a sequenced segment and query BQ with that? Or do you want to create a report with the pages URI's with the PVs, drop-offs etc?

Comment: I have created sequence segments - but how Do I use those to query big query?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your table in BigQuery, you can run a query and save the result to Google Sheets [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/05/bigquery-integrates-with-google-drive). There is also a connector exists for Excel [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-connector-for-excel). This third-party offers an Add-on to connect BigQuery with Google Sheets but I haven't tried [[3]](https://www.owox.com/products/bi/pipeline/google-bigquery-to-google-sheets/).

Comment: From your comments I understood you already have your data in BigQuery. Is this the case? If not this guide [(1)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en) explains how to export data from Google Analytics 360 to BigQuery.

Comment: HI - I have the data in big query- but I am pretty stuck on how we can generate the sql to create the funnels - there seems to be a lot of approaches but no one recommended for user based funnels ( similar to custom funnel)

Comment: Have a look at this [guide](https://online-behavior.com/analytics/funnel-analysis), it explains basic structure of a SQL query for funnel analysis where Google Analytics is linked with BigQuery.